# Opening a PDF File in Android

Tags: android, pdf, file-io, viewer

I am trying to open a link to a pdf file and display the pdf when a button is clicked on the device.  What is the best way to go about this?  I would like to be able to not use a 3rd party software.  So I know that I might have to convert the file to something else.

Comment: Take a look at [this][1] quiestion, hope this helps.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530780/android-is-there-any-free-pdf-library-for-android

Comment: you can try with this..https://github.com/bitfield66/PdfViewerAndroid_Offline

Comment: The easiest way is to simply load the pdf using Google docs viewer.  This way it can be done in a web view.  But the downside is there is not a lot of functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this inside your Button's click listener:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/example.pdf");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),”application/pdf”);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```

You should check if any PDF reading application is available before using this code.

If you are planning to implement your own PDF reader then refer [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773576/are-there-any-free-pdf-parsing-libraries-that-work-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create your own  pdf Reader For that u have to download **PDF VIEWER.jar**
then try this code

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    String[] pdflist;
    File[] imagelist;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     //setContentView(R.layout.main);

     File images = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
     imagelist = images.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
      public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
       return ((name.endsWith(".pdf")));
      }
     });
     pdflist = new String[imagelist.length];
     for (int i = 0; i < imagelist.length; i++) {
      pdflist[i] = imagelist[i].getName();
     }
     this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pdflist));
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
     super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
     String path = imagelist[(int) id].getAbsolutePath();
     openPdfIntent(path);
    }

    private void openPdfIntent(String path) {
     try {
      final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
      intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, path);
      startActivity(intent);
     } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
}
```

**second.java**

```
public class Second extends PdfViewerActivity {

      @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        public int getPreviousPageImageResource() {
         return R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        }

        public int getNextPageImageResource() {
             return R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        }

        public int getZoomInImageResource() {
             return R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        }

        public int getZoomOutImageResource() {
             return R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        }

        public int getPdfPasswordLayoutResource() {
             return R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        }

        public int getPdfPageNumberResource() {
             return R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        }

        public int getPdfPasswordEditField() {
             return R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        }

        public int getPdfPasswordOkButton() {
             return R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        }

        public int getPdfPasswordExitButton() {
             return R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        }

        public int getPdfPageNumberEditField() {
             return R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        }

}
```